# javascript indexOf the result of map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, indexof

I am doing a map of my array to get the max of it, and then I do indexOf to get the index of the result:

```
var dates = [
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 26,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "West",
    "MeasureDate": "2023-04-12T15:13:11.733Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": "2017-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  }
]
```

and here is my attempt:

```
var result = dates
    .map(x => x.MeasureDate)
    .indexOf(new Date(Math.max(
        ...dates.map(a => new Date(a.MeasureDate))
    )))

console.log('latest date', result)
```

but the result is `-1`.
how can i fix it to get the correct index of the result?

Comment: Hint: Your current code calls `.indexOf()` on an array of strings looking for a `Date` object.

Comment: Your code is difficult to debug because you're trying to one-line it. It looks cool, but it makes it more difficult to read and maintain. Try separating it out into multiple statements.

Comment: The title of the post "javascript indexOf the result of map function" is neither a question nor a statement. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: why so many loops, one loop is needed with a simple reduce.

Comment: Further to what epascarello said, if you do use a single loop and the dates will always be in the same timezone you don't even need to convert to `Date`, you can do a string compare on that property.

Answer (score 1):

It can get the index of max datetime.

```js
var dates = [
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 26,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "West",
    "MeasureDate": "2023-04-12T15:13:11.733Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": "2017-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  }
]
var result = dates.map(x => (new Date(x.MeasureDate)).getTime()).indexOf(Math.max(...dates.map(a=>(new Date(a.MeasureDate)).getTime())))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is one loop to map, another loop to map, and one loop to look up the index. That is a lot of loops to find one thing.

Break it down to one loop. Store the index with the greatest and keep looping over the array until you are gone. It is a basic max/min problem that every interview does.

```js
var dates = [
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": "2019-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 26,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "West",
    "MeasureDate": "2023-04-12T15:13:11.733Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  },
  {
    "Address": 25,
    "AlertType": 1,
    "Area": "North",
    "MeasureDate": "2017-02-01T00:01:01.001Z",
    "MeasureValue": -1
  }
]

const asDate = dates.reduce((obj, details, index) => {
  const temp = {
   index, date : new Date(details.MeasureDate)
  }
  return !obj || obj.date < temp.date ? temp : obj;
}, null).index

const asString = dates.reduce((obj, details, index) => {
  const temp = {
   index, date : details.MeasureDate
  }
  return !obj || obj.date < temp.date ? temp : obj;
}, null).index

console.log("result", asDate, asString)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is using findIndex function and compare date through getTime

```
const getTime = value => new Date(value).getTime();
const result = dates.findIndex( item => getTime(item.MeasureDate) === Math.max(...dates.map( item => getTime(item.MeasureDate))))
```